# Editing style tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to edit some styles within style tag. Is there a way to get specific selector from style to modify? For example if I have:

```
<style>
  h1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

and I want to change background color to #123456 is there a way to change it with jquery? Or I have to write some function to work on $("style").text(); ?

Comment: Why not just edit the CSS code? If you need to do this programatically, add a class to the element.

Comment: `$('h1').css('background-color','green')`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I need to edit the content of style tag, not to overwrite the css rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work as long as the page doesn't change after its loaded:

```
$(function() {
  $("h1").css("background-color":"#123456");
});
```

If you really really wanted to edit the style then maybe something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("style").each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("background-color: red","background-color: #123456" );
  });

});
```

But that seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the function be called from some event rather than on ready?

Comment: Maybe not the OP isn't very specific. +1

Comment: Good point, hadn't thought of that, although fairly trivial to change my example to a function call.

Comment: I prefer second variant even if it looks ugly. Well, I had thought about something similar but did not know if there is an easier way. My rules should be exportable, so, having them in one place will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use jQuery to access the CSS definitions, you use it to access the DOM element and change the style directly.

```
$('h1').css('background-color', '#123456');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. I have to change it within style tag as I said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

similar to defining css in jquery

```
$('h1').css('background-color', 'red');
```

you can warp it up in any function event needed.

Like on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1').css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

or may be some other custom function like like click, hover, select etc.

```
$(function() {
  $("h1").css("background-color":"red");
});
```